# How is UK statutory redundancy pay affected by a switch to part time?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, unemployment

I know that UK redundancy pay is based on a week's pay for each full year worked, with some adjustment for age which we can ignore.  There are also various caps and minimum periods to ignore.

But consider a situation where a full-time employee has just under 5 years service (i.e. would only be entitled to 4 weeks redundancy pay).  An opportunity arises for a few months part time (50%, same salary pro-rata) work, taking the length of service to over 5 years, and therefore 5 weeks redundancy pay.  Would this 5 weeks then be 5 weeks at 50%, meaning a reduction in redundancy pay for working longer?

Very closely related bonus question: If the option arose to be made redundant at just under 5 years then come back part time for a few months (accruing no further redundancy pay as the service would be less than a year), is there a minimum period to be out of work or out of that particular employment without causing eligibility problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are entitled [to the *average* of what you have earned over the past twelve weeks](https://www.gov.uk/calculate-your-redundancy-pay) (up to the date of the redundancy notice) - so in this case, probably about equal to 75% of full-time salary, rather than half. (That link has a calculator: it may be worth plugging the details in and seeing what it suggests)

However, [per Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/leaving-a-job/redundancy/redundancy-pay/), there is a special case if you agree to "short-time working" - which may or may not be the case here, depending on exactly how it is defined.

> If you’ve been laid off or put on short-time working, and then made redundant, your redundancy pay will be based on your usual weekly pay when you did your normal hours.
>
> The only time this won’t apply is if you agreed to a permanent change in the number of hours you work.

Comment: Unfortunately this would be more than 12 weeks at the lower rate so the averaging wouldn't help.  And it would be a different role that I'd have to apply for so I doubt the exemption CA describe could be made to apply - not worth risking.  The calculator, BTW, assumes a fixed salary so the averaging is up to the user.

Comment: Although based on how the same employer has handled fixed term extensions in the past "at the date of the redundancy notice"  *could* turn out to be at the start of the part time bit